# PCA/LDA interpretation and suitable clustering method

Tags: clustering, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am exploring the data on suicides from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/russellyates88/suicide-rates-overview-1985-to-2016

I wanted to perform the dimensionality reduction to identify possible clusters, like, for example, in this plot for IRIS dataset (taken from https://towardsdatascience.com/dimension-reduction-techniques-with-python-f36ca7009e5c):

[image]

However, performing PCA on the mentioned dataset (for suicides) gives me this (color means the suicide rates):

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret it since it does not give so clear clusters as the IRIS example. Should I understand these different lines as clusters as well? Just not of the circular form?

If so, which clustering algorithm would give me some good results? I know that KMeans will most likely not work due to the received shape.

Or should I just drop the dimensionality reduction completely for this dataset? Since even there are line on the plot after dimensionality reduction, the suicide rate (color) do not vary SO much between them?

Code snippet (note that I performed PCA only on continuous variables, is it correct or should the categorical once be included as well?):

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', index_col=0)
pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='full')
pca_np = pca.fit_transform(df[['year', 'gdp_per_capita', 'population', 'gdp_for_year']].values)
plt.scatter(pca_np[:, 0], pca_np[:, 1], c=df.suicides_no);
```

Another though: is some preprocessing step missing? Maybe people familiar with this or similar dataset have some insights for it?

Comment: Might be useful to add a code snippet and also add a legend for the colour of your graph as per the iris example you've already given

Comment: Also to add might be worth going through the other kernels for the data set on kaggle as some people have also done clustering on the data and may answer your question

Comment: @vigos I've added code snippet (but for now it's basically just read a file-perform PCA). I was going through other kernels, but I've seen clustering on separate variables, not dimensionality reduction.

Comment: I'd remove year ( as I'd treat it as categorical here) and just try pca on the other  variables, also have you scaled the variables as per the iris example you gave? Maybe try going back over that page and see what you might have missed